# Git: set the tip of a branch to a particular commit

Tags: git, branch

Suppose one has a branch named **my-branch** with three commits like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

At first the tip of **my-branch** is pointing at aaa. If one does `git reset --hard HEAD^` the tip will start pointing at bbb. The same command will cause the tip of **my-branch** to point to ccc. How can one point the tip again at aaa or bbb?

One option would be to checkout aaa or bbb (detach HEAD) and then checkout a new branch, say **new-branch**, delete **my-branch** and use the new one. I also suppose that something like `git branch -f my-branch bbb` should work, but when I try this, I get

```
fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `git reset --hard <commit-ID>` to re-re-adjust the current branch.  Use the reflog to find the ID, if needed—or, even simpler, if the reflog says that this is (say) `HEAD@{2}`, just `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` (note that each `git reset` renumbers the *`n`* in `@{n}`).

The `git merge` method in [Francisco Puga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076231/1256452) also works fine if that merge is a fast-forward merge.  (If you pick a wrong one you'll get a real merge, which is fine if that's what you want, or you can `git reset --hard HEAD^` to undo it if not.)  Again you can give the raw SHA-1 or the reflog name.  As an added bonus:

`git merge --ff-only id`

will *only* "slide the branch-name forward" (towards a new tip like `aaa` or `bbb`), never do a "regular" merge, so it's a good way to make sure you are using an appropriate ID.

Answer (score 2):

If those commits are present in another branch, say *master*, you can use git merge to get it back to *my-branch*.

To restore the commit with hash bbb onto *my-branch*, use

```
git checkout my-brach
git merge bbb
```

If those commit are not present anymore in your branches you must use [git reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tip of a branch to a particular commit using date based sha1 expressions     such as "branchname@{yesterday}"

E.g., git checkout testbranch@{yesterday}

However, this will result in detached HEAD state, as already mentioned by you.

Comment: Instead of checking out a new branch to avoid detached HEAD state you can use "-B" option of checkout.
git checkout -B testbranch

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check out to bbb to avoid the "*fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.*" message. Then you can change the HEAD to bbb with *branch -f*. Finally, check-out to this branch, otherwise you are in a detached HEAD.

So, do the following:

```
git co bbb
git branch -f my-branch bbb
git co my-branch
```

.

```
Before:          After:
>aaa          aaa
 bbb         >bbb
 ccc          ccc
```